# Force auto increment to follow another suequence

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing invoices. Those invoices are inserted via a VB.NET program I have written. Using auto increment my invoices get their invoiceid.

I now have invoiceid's like
1055
1056
1057
...

I also have another database (from another bought software program) that generate invoices, and I use a cron job to import certain invoices into my main table, but they get the prefix 99. Those invoices do not have the same sequence. I do not use auto increment to number them, but I use the original ID (from the other database) + the 99 prefix. In my main table I have invoiceid's from the secondary database like this:

992013055
992013064
992013078

So, this makes that my main table looks like this:

992013055
1055
1056
992013064
1057
992013078
...

Now the thing is, I want the auto increment only follow the 'main' sequence. So in the example above, the next auto increment value should be 1058, but using normal auto increment it would be 992013079.
Is there a way to force this? Or should I "reset" the auto increment value after the cron job, something like "ALTER TABLE invoices AUTO_INCREMENT=bla +1". I guess 'bla' should be a new select to get the highest value in the column that does not start with 99, not sure how to do this. Off course when I get to invoice 9900, this would be a problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Even if you tried the `ALTER TABLE invoices AUTO_INCREMENT=bla +1` command, it would not work, as MySQL makes sure the value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` is higher than the highest value in the column.

Basically you shouldn't use the value in your autoincremented column for anything else than primary key, so that you don't really need to care about what these values are and what sequence they follow. After all nobody sees them and they're only used by computer.

If however you used these values for something that's visible for the end user... well your users will just need to adjust to the fact, that their invoces start from `99` now. Either that, or you need to renumber them, which is hell of a work and likely to introduce errors to your data.

Answer (score 3):

i would create another column or table that links in this external id and do not try to layer them in to your id column like you are attempting.

for instance add a column called external_id and simply populate that one with the 99 values - and keep your autoincrement value chugging along properly with your regular numbers.